# 3 locations for SSHd configuration

Tags: macos, ssh

So I want to harden my SSH daemon when Remote Login is enabled.

So far I've found:

- `/private/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` -> protected by SIP
- `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Why are there 3 locations, and what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the specific files you'll see that there are actually only two files (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and `/private/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is the same file unless your setup is non-standard).

- `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` is used by the system to start `sshd`, usually you don't need to change this
- `/private/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is the global configuration file for `sshd`, and the place where you need to change whatever is required to harden SSH on your Mac.

Comment: How would make changes to `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf` persistent across updates? SIP overwrites all files in `/etc/` even for minor updates, which can be very frustrating.

Comment: @Picard It is a pain indeed, there is a whole bunch of files in `/etc` which get overwritten with each update nowadays. I have a little script which uses `sudo install ...` to put these files back, and run this manually after each update.

Comment: ok thanks, that what I thought about doing as well, especially for pam sudo, which I secure with security keys or the apple watch.